# Docker - eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.7 Error: Address not available

Tags: docker, mosquitto

I'm trying to run mosquitto as docker container in windows 10. Getting below error log Address not available.

```
1614449526: mosquitto version 2.0.7 starting

1614449526: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.

1614449526: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.

1614449526: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access.

1614449526: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.

1614449526: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.

**1614449526: Error: Address not available**

1614449526: mosquitto version 2.0.7 running
```

Could anyone advise how to solve this error?

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly: https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2040

Comment: Please include the command that you're using to the run the container.

Comment: add `listener 1883` to  mosquitto.conf and mount => mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.

Answer (score 10):

I hadd the same issue.
My solution was:
Enter to mosquitto container item from portainer.io. Then log into the console of the mosquitto's container. Select the command: `/bin/sh` for log in.
In the command line adjust the `mosquitto.conf` located in: `/mosquitto/config`
Change the following parameters: Uncomment and fixed

```
listener 1883
persistence true
allow_anonymous true
```

later, exit from command console and restart mosquitto container...and ready !!
check logs!

Answer (score 4):

i followed Stéphane Trottier's suggestion but ran into issues b/c of the port and an outdated config change:

```
allow_anonymous true
listener 2883
protocol mqtt
```

i also used port 2883 instead since it seems 8883 is for tls so i was getting connection refused errors on the client and protocol errors on the server. my docker compose looks like this:

```
  mqtt:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    volumes:
      - ./mqtt/config:/mosquitto/config
    user: "1000:1000"
    ports:
      - 1883:2883
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. MQTT-Explorer could afterwards connect on port 1883 even without the mapping to `2883`

Answer (score 3):

both azegurelabs and Stéphane Trottier answers worked for me.
but the easier and more accurate solution is to just run image with default provided conf

```
docker run -it --rm --name mosquitto -p 1883:1883 eclipse-mosquitto:2.0 mosquitto -c /mosquitto-no-auth.conf
```

or to run image with your config file

```
docker run -it -p 1883:1883 -v <absolute-path-to-configuration-file>:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf eclipse-mosquitto:<version>
```

you can read more here: [mosquitto docker github page](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/master/docker/2.0)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue yesterday... Generally, some OSs require more permissions to run services on ports lower than 2000. This is how I made it work for me. I'm just running this for a hobby project. For work I would do things differently.

- added local mosquitto folder and placed mosquitto.conf file in it.
- added allow_anonymous true
- changed port to something higher than 2000.
- mount local config volume in docker

```
allow_anonymous true
port 8883
```

I run it via docker compose file.

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mosquitto:
      image: eclipse-mosquitto
      hostname: mosquitto
      container_name: mosquitto
      ports:
        - "8883:8883"
      volumes: 
        - ./mosquitto:/mosquitto/config
      networks:
        - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
```

The error is gone from my logs and I can connect to it just fine on that port.

```
1614505908: The 'port' option is now deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use 'listener' instead.
1614505908: mosquitto version 2.0.7 starting
1614505908: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1614505908: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1614505908: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1614505908: mosquitto version 2.0.7 running
```

looks like I'll have to replace port with listener at some point soon.