# Error: Address in use when deploying MQTT 2.0.14 as container using Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, containers, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to run mqtt as a container using Docker desktop. But as per the logs getting an error Address in use when running the command:

```
mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf
```

Below is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    container_name: mosquitto_container
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
    volumes:
      - ./config:/mosquitto/config
```

And the mosquitto.conf file:

```
listener 1883 127.0.0.1
allow_anonymous true
```

In all the articles over the internet and also in the mqtt docs it is mentioned that we have to specify listener in the conf file which I have added.

My goal is to run mqtt as a container and then from a .net utililty publish the messages to the broker.

I am using the Docker version v20.10.10 running on my Windows 10 and mqtt image version is 2.0.14.

Please guide me.

Comment: This helped in my case https://stackoverflow.com/a/73886321/217408

Answer (score 2):

The problem will most likely be because you are already running mosquitto on your docker host machine (windows) on port 1883. So when Docker ties to bind the container version to the same port it will clash.

Either stop the version running on the Windows host machine or change the port the docker version is mapped to in the `ports` section of the docker compose file.

Also possibly you already have a running container bound to that port. Running `docker ps -a` will show what containers exist and what ports they are bound to.

Comment: With `docker-compose up -d` I get these entries in the `mosquitto.log`
`1689411873: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
1689411873: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1689411873: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1689411873: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1689411873: Error: Address in use`
So the docker image tries to listening twice to the same address+port and seems to fall over its own feet.